# How to retrieve all user information from Firebase into memory right after login and use it?

Tags: android, firebase, memory

I made a mobile application with Firebase Authentication and Storage. The entire profile of a user contains the following fields: 
- Name
- Address
- Profile IMG thumbnail
- An admin checker

I want that as soon as an user logs into the application to retrieve all that data (including the image) right into ram memory so it can be instantly loaded when you visit the profile page for example. Right now the app sends a request and retrieves data every single time you visit the profile page and I don't want that anymore.

Here is the code that gets the data (in the profile activity):

```
StorageReference profileThumbnailPath = storageReference.child("profile_image").child(userID + "_thumb" + ".jpg");
    profileThumbnailPath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String imageURL = uri.toString();
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL).into(profilePic);

    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        String error = Objects.requireNonNull(exception.getMessage());
        errorTxt.setText(error);
        errorTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        String name_string = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getString("name");
        String address_string= Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getString("address");
        String admin_check = task.getResult().getString("is_admin");
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                name_textview.setText(name_string);
                address_textview.setText(city_string);
                assert admin_check != null;
                if (admin_check.equals("1")) {
                    admin_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            String error = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage();
            errorTxt.setText(error);
            errorTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

So how can I load all this data into memory and instantly use it in other activities?

Comment: Also before anyone asks, I used Storage Reference for profile thumbnail because glide gave some sinister crashes with Firestroe collection, idk why.

Comment: You should use Glide Library. Once you get the images, you'll have all cached. There is no need to get them over and over again.